# calling javascript function in an html/php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was creating a website wherein one part, the user must input his phone number and also complete the google ReCaptcha.

Once the google ReCaptcha is completed successfully, a javascript function would be called which would send an SMS to the phone number that the user entered.

This is how the front page looks like.

[image]]

Once the submit button is pressed, the PHP file checks whether the reCAPTCHA is completed successfully. If completed successfully, then it should call the sendOTP() function of the javascript file named "verification.js". However, I do not know how to call this sendOTP() function of the javascript file in this case.

Here is the PHP file containing the PHP code as well as the HTML form:

```html
<?php
$ph_number = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
        $secret = "secret key";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        //echo $ip;
        $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$ip";
        $fire = file_get_contents($url);
        //echo $fire;
        $_SESSION['ph_number'] = $ph_number;
        $data = json_decode($fire);
        if ($data->success == true)
        {
            echo "success";
            $_SESSION['ph_number'] = $ph_number;
            //    <<<<<<<<<-------------------Here the sendOTP() should be called.
            
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Please fill recaptcha";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "captcha error";
    }
}
else
{
}
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>OTP SMS</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="error"></div>
      <form action="validate-captcha.php" id="frm-mobile-verification" method="POST">
        <div class="form-heading">Mobile Number Verification</div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="number" id="mobile" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter the 8 digit mobile" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ph_number'] ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="verification.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Here is the javascript code (containing sendOTP() ) just in case it's needed:

```js
function sendOTP() {
  $(".error").html("").hide();
  var number = $("#mobile").val();
  if (number.length == 8 && number != null && (number.indexOf(5) == 0 || number.indexOf(6) == 0 || number.indexOf(9) == 0)) {
    var input = {
      "mobile_number": number,
      "action": "send_otp"
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: 'controller.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: input,
      success: function(response) {
        $(".container").html(response);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(".error").html('Please enter a valid Hong Kong number!')
    $(".error").show();
  }
}
```

If I fill the phone number and validate reCAPTCHA properly, this is what is being shown up right now:

[image]

Can somebody please tell me how I can edit the code so that once the reCAPTCHA is completed successfully, the sendOTP() of the JS file is called?

Comment: Next time take more care in formatting your question

Comment: What's wrong with `echo '<script>sendOTP()</script>` after captcha success? Just pass the number as an argument instead of trying to get it from the DOM.

Comment: @MarkusAO you mean within the php part of the code? It does not work cause in this case, sendOTP() is not considered as a function but rather <script>sendOTP()</script> is considered as a string.

Comment: Well it's obviously just a string for PHP, however it's a function call in the browser HTML.

Comment: are you suggesting me to put echo '<script>sendOTP()</script> underneath if ($data->success == true) ?

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the function in a condition in your html header, as long as your `sendOTP()` function is included before the condition, something like this should work :

```
  <head>
    <title>OTP SMS</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="verification.js"></script>
    <?=(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && $data->success) ? "<script>sentOTP()</script>" : ""?>
  </head>
```

Comment: Warning: Undefined variable $data in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\OTP.php on line 36
Warning: Attempt to read property "success" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\OTP.php on line 36
 
these 2 errors pop up then. Firstly, $data is defined in PHP, not before that. So in HTML, I guess $data remains undefined? secondly, success remains null. Also, can you please also explain what you mean by sendOTP() function included before the condition?

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work now.

And what I mean is that the script containing the ```sendOTP()``` function should be loaded BEFORE the call to said function. Otherwise your browser will tell you that ```sendOTP()``` is not defined.
Is that function in **verification.js** ?

Comment: Yeah sendOTP() is defined in verification.js. However, I tried your most recent edit, but it still doesn't work. One noticeable thing is that on the network section of the inspect window, the verification.js is not even accessed when the button is pressed, meaning that for some reason, verification.js or the sendOTP() is not called at all.

Comment: Yes because as I said it twice, verification.js has to be loaded BEFORE you run that function. I don't know in what words to say it really.
Edited my answer once more. Include verification.js BEFORE you call sendOTP() !

Comment: The same problem persists. Am I supposed to bring any changes to the PHP side of the code? No, right? In that case, I am confused as to why your answer does not get the work done. Also, by saying "Include verification.js BEFORE you call sendOTP() " you mean the use of <script src="verification.js"></script> line, right?

Comment: any idea on why it still does not work? The warnings are gone now; it's just that after the validation of captcha, the sendOTP() function from verification.js is not executed.